# Cast from NSMutableDictionary? to unrelated type [AnyHashble:Any] always fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics, swift3

I updated to Swift 3 and I'm using Google Analytics in my project. Originally I had this line of code working:

```
 tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

After the Swift 3 conversion tool finished, it changed it to this:

```
tracker?.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [AnyHashable: Any])
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type NSMutableDictionary! to type [AnyHashable:Any] in coercion
```

I can get rid of this error by changing the line to:

```
tracker?.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as? [AnyHashable: Any])
```

However this gives me the warning in the title. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this a bug in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Swift Team (or Apple?) thinks that is a bug. But in fact, Swift 3 runtime **can** convert value of type `NSMutableDictionary!` to type `[AnyHashable:Any]` using `as!`.

To suppress the warning, please try this:

```
tracker?.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as NSDictionary as! [AnyHashable : Any])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this (safer) way:

```
    if let eventTracker = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() {
        var eventTrackerSwift: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
        for item in eventTracker {
            if let key = item.key as? AnyHashable {
                eventTrackerSwift[key] = item.value
            }
        }
        tracker.send(eventTrackerSwift)
    }
```